# Changing HTML list item to active in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am loading my navbar into each page with `$("#navbar-partial").load("navbar.html)` at the bottom of the page in script tags.

The navbar list code is below:

```
<ul id="main-nav" class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li>
    <a href="a.html"></a>
  </li>                     
  <li>
    <a href="b.html"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="c.html"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="d.html"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Ive tried this and some variations of this but cant get it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

This is in the same script tag at the bottom of the html page, after the load call.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use delegation

```
$(document).on('click', ".nav li", function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the content isn't present on DOM ready (given the asynchronous nature of Ajax), you'll need to use `on()` to bind the `click` handler to an ancestor element, which is present in the DOM at the point of DOM-ready, the element with `id="navbar-partial"`, into which you're loading the new content:

```
// selecting the element present on DOM-ready:
// binding the 'click' event that's fired on elements
// matching the '.nav li' selector:
$('#navbar-partial').on('click', '.nav li', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

You could bind to an element further up the DOM tree, but binding to the closest element is reduces the amount of bubbling required to detect the event.

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: still no luck, im checking the html in console and the active tag isnt getting added.

Comment: Unfortunately, without more context, I can't offer any useful information; incidentally, you know your initial selector, `$("navbar-partial")` is erroneous? It's not looking for an `id`, but for an *element*, of `<navbar-partial>` (which obviously doesn't exist).

Comment: I mistyped it in the question, sorry about that. Edited it